# Activating a Foundation 6 Reveal Modal with Javascript

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm currently activating a Foundation 6 Reveal Modal in the following way:

```
<p><button class="button" data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</button></p>

    <div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>

      <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>

      <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>

      <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>

      <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">

        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

      </button>

    </div>
```

How could I change above code to activate it with Javascript instead?

Thanks!